# Compactness of intersection of a compact set and an open set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

If $K \subset E_1 \cup E_2$, where $K$ is compact and $E_1, E_2$ are disjoint open subsets of a topological space, is $K \cap E_1$ compact? Is that always the case if $E_1, E_2$ are not disjoint?

I've seen other threads that have this, so I was wondering why the solution I thought of is incorrect:

Let $U_{\alpha}$ be an open covering of $K$. Then because $K$ is compact, there is a finite subcovering $U_1, U_2, \ldots, U_N \in U_{\alpha}$ that cover $K$. But then $U_1, \ldots, U_N, E_1$ is a finite collection of open sets that covers $K$ and $E_1$, so it covers $K \cap E_1$, and so $K \cap E_1$ must be compact.

Comment: If $E_1$ and $E_2$ are not disjoint, you might as well take $E_2=X$ (the whole space); so you're just asking, if $K$ is compact and $E_1$ is open, is $K\cap E_1$ compact?

Comment: If $E_1,E_2$ don't have to be disjoint, here is a counterexample: $K=[0,1]$, $E_1=(0,1)$, $E_2=\mathbb R$. $E_1$ and $E_2$ are open subsets of the space $\mathbb R$, $K$ is a compact subset of $E_1\cup E_2$, but $K\cap E_1=E_1$ is not compact.

Comment: If your argument were correct (which it is not), it would prove that any subset of a compact set is compact.

Comment: Yes, I realize the conclusion of this "proof" is incorrect, but I was wondering where the flaw was that led to this false conclusion.

Comment: To prove that $K\cap E_1$ is compact, you have to show that any open cover of $K\cap E_1$ has a finite subcover. Proving that an open cover of $K$ has a finite subcover doesn't do it.

Comment: Fix open cover of the intersection and extract a finite subcover ..if you can

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you... I can't believe I overlooked something as obvious as this.

Comment: @A.Smith for whatever reason I initially also thought your argument was correct, but spotted the mistake once I started thinking in terms of definitions. It seems so reasonable that since $K\cap E_1\subseteq K$, taking a finite subcover of $K$ would do the trick, but then we wouldn't be checking all the cases.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your space is Hausdorff $K\setminus E_2=K\cap E_1$ and $K\setminus E_2$ is compact. On second thoughts you don't need Hausdorff property!.

Comment: Where do you think you need Hausdorff? If $E_1$ and $E_2$ are disjoint and $K\subseteq E_1\cup E_2$ then $K\cap E_1=K\setminus E_2$ is just set theory. If $K$ is compact and $E_2$ is open then $K\setminus E_2$ is compact in any topological space.

Comment: @bof You are right.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof should start with a cover $\mathcal{U}$ (WLOG by open sets of $X$) of $K \cap E_1$, and produce a finite subcover of that:

Add the one set $E_2$ to $\mathcal{U}$ and we have an open cover of $K$ (any set in $K$ lies in $E_1$ or $E_2$ and the first ones are covered by $\mathcal{U}$ the other by $E_2$..) and so $\mathcal{U} \cup \{E_2\}$ has a finite subcover $\mathcal{U}'$ and then $\mathcal{U}'\setminus \{E_2\}$ is still finite (smaller than the finite $\mathcal{U}'$) and a subcover of $\mathcal{U}$. So $K \cap E_1$ is compact.

Alternatively note that $K\cap E_1 = K \cap (X\setminus E_2)$ and thus is a closed subset of the compact $K$ and hence compact too.